# Get confirm-box value via code-behind at C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, code-behind, confirm

I want to get the value from side to confirm aspx

```
bool type=false;

 type=   ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "exampleScript", "confirm('are you confirm?')", true);

if(type){
...
}
```

How do I get the value of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't sound like best of the approach (I mean you could show pop-up client side)... However, if you want to accomplish this...

You have have a hidden asp:Button on your aspx and attach a event handler to it and write the code that you want to have executed upon clicking Yes on the confirm button.

And modify your RegisterStartupScript as below

```
type=   ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "exampleScript", "if(confirm('are you confirm?')) { document.getElementById('btn').click(); } ", true);
```

Comment: it's work ,thank you:)  I shared on my solution, http://weblogboard.wordpress.com/2013/09/02/get-return-value-javascript-confirm-from-code-behind-c/

Answer (score 0):

```
bool type=false;

  "return confirm('are you confirm?')"

if(type){
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. The below code worked for me.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "exampleScript", "if(confirm(\"Are you sure?\")){ document.getElementById('Button1').click(); }", true);
<asp:Button ID="Button1" Visible="true" SkinID="button"  OnClick="Button1_Click"  runat="server" />
```

Use a `hidden button` and write the code on click event of the button. Please note that don't use `visible="false"` property to make the button hidden. Instead use `style="display:none"`