# Getting Gidview Hidden field value on button click in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Gridview `dtAppend`. I want that when I press delete button the selected row record should be deleted from users table.

I first used `button field` in gridview, as:

```
<asp:ButtonField Text="Delete" CommandName="DeleteRow" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-danger btn-small" ControlStyle-ForeColor="White" />
<asp:TemplateField visible="false" ItemStyle-Width="0px">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField" Visible="false" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("userId") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

My client says to show JavaScript alert and on clicking yes the record should be deleted. I cannot write `onClientClick` for button field so I am being forced to use normal Asp button.

on `rowCommand` of gridview I am getting the hidden field value in this code

```
if (e.CommandName == "DeleteRow")
{
    GridViewRow row = dtAppend.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)];
    hidden1 = (HiddenField)row.Cells[6].FindControl("HiddenField");
    string text = Convert.ToString((HiddenField)row.Cells[6].FindControl("HiddenField"));
    Session["dtIdDel"] = hidden1.Value;
}
```

i am getting thew value in Session but i need above code working Button_ClickEvent like below

```
 protected void deleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = dtAppend.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)];
        hidden1 = (HiddenField)row.Cells[6].FindControl("HiddenField");
        string text = Convert.ToString((HiddenField)row.Cells[6].FindControl("HiddenField"));
        Session["dtIdDel"] = hidden1.Value;}
```

this is where 'e.CommandArgument' gives Error
I cannot use the above code in normal button click as it gives error in `e.CommandArgument`

Any help?

Comment: below article seems to be a help for you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17920125/get-confirm-box-value-via-code-behind-at-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would be easy way, instead of using hidden field.

```
<asp:LinkButton CommandArgument='<%# Eval("userId") %>' OnClientClick="if (!confirm('Are you sure you want delete?')) return false;" CommandName="DeleteRow" ID="eliminar" runat="server" Text="delete"/>

if (e.CommandName == "DeleteRow")
{
    int userId = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Exactly the way i wanted Thank So much Mate .. Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2):

You Better Remove `Visible="false"` . Because, the value that has to be binded for hidden field will not be binded in to the field if `Visible="false"` is there.  Any how its a hidden field, so make it `Visible="true"`

EDIT :

How you handled the RowDataBound event of the Grid, are you assigning the CommandArgument for each row, other wise the above concept will not work in Paging. Refer as below

Ex : -

```
Button btnMail = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("lnkMail");
btnMail.CommandArgument = e.Row.RowIndex.ToString();
```

Comment: i updated the question i amgetting hidden field value in session on gridView_RowCommand but i need that on Click Event

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can remove `visible="false"`

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("userId") %>' />
```

Comment: sorry my mistake i getting the value in  Session["dtIdDel"] = hidden1.Value;

Answer (score 1):

You can simply send ID as `command argument`

or

Try the code as below:

```
var ID = int.Parse(((HiddenField)item.FindControl("HiddenField1")).Value);
sql = "delete from tablename where id=" + ID;
```

Comment: Exactly the way i wanted Thank So much Mate .. Appreciate it :)